# iOS swift check if URL accessed via ipv6

Tags: ios, swift, ipv6

Is there a way to check if a website is ipv6 compatible before loading it to a webview via url request?

I am asking this because I want to publish an app thats main layout loads a webview first and the url it loads isnt ipv6 compatible. Now its giving off a white screen due to which apple is rejecting my app from being published. Now that solution I want to apply is:

```
if(connection is ipv6) {
    //do something to prevent loading the webview
} else {
    //load the webview normally
}
```

but this is my first time using xCode and SWIFT, even MAC just installed it on vmware workstation.

edit : extra information, the application is just a single layout that has a webview to load a mobile friendly website nothing more than that:

```
webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(URL: URL(string: "link")!))
```

the review guy from apple:

> From Apple
>   Performance - 2.1
>
> We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad
>   running iOS 10.2.1 on Wi-Fi connected to an IPv6 network.
>
> Specifically, your app launches to empty white screen.
>
> Please see attached screenshots for details.

and the screenshot is just a blank white image

Comment: If you follow Apple's guidelines, and you test this on an IPv6-only network as Apple describes, then this shouldn't be a problem. Specifically excluding IPv6 is the opposite of what Apple now requires.

Comment: @RonMaupin what do you mean? I am kinda lost on this. Apple sure has alot more limitations than android has and I have absolutely no experience with apple or its sowtwares/devices

Comment: Apple requires that your application work on an IPv6-only network, and that is how your application is tested. There are instructions on how to set up such a test network.

Comment: @RonMaupin idk if you understood me wrong or I am being confused here but, the IP that I am trying to connect via my application to does not support ipv6 connections so even if apple requires it and my system does not support it then what?

Comment: You will automatically support IPv4, but you need to support IPv6, too. The thinking is that everything is moving to IPv6, and servers, etc. that only support IPv4 today will support IPv6 shortly. Excluding IPv6 is short-sighted.

Comment: so what do i do? I still dont have a clear idea of how to manage this. I do not own the server or manage it. talking with administrators of the server will take months or maybe more as they are slow. I need to sort this out quickly

Comment: The problem is _not_ that the web site doesn't support IPv6. It is simply a bug in the application. Unfortunately you haven't described anything about the actual problem you're having, so it's impossible to give you an answer.

Comment: @MichaelHampton its just an application with webview nothing else. it loads an already running mobile website into the webview basically nothing else using webView.loadRequest(URLRequest(URL: URL(string: "link")!))

Comment: So what is the URL? What is the error that returns?

Comment: sorry I added some more info to the question now I should of done it earlier, I thought its a common thing because when I searched over google alot of people had the problem but no solution. Read the question again please

Comment: Are you using `Reachability`?

Comment: no I am not using it as I said I have no experience with SWIFT or xcode

Comment: Is the only way to make the server support IPv6? Is there any other way to solve it only on iOS?